# Can you guys help me with my laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

It says

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message
>   "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `seller` where `id` = 1 limit 1)

I used `laravel 5.4`

I'm using this code in my Controller class to connect to my database

```
$dataSeller = seller::where('username_seller', $kiriman->username)->where('password_seller',$kiriman->password)->get();

        // $dataSeller = seller::find($id);
        // $dataSeller->username = $kiriman['username_seller'];
        // $dataSeller->password = $kiriman['password_seller'];

        // $dataAdmin = admin::find($id);
        // $dataAdmin->username = $kiriman['username_admin'];
        // $dataAdmin->password = $kiriman['password_admin'];

        //Function login admin
        $dataAdmin = admin::where('username_admin', $kiriman->username)->where('password_admin',$kiriman->password)->get();

        if (count($dataSeller)>0) {
            //Login berhasil seller
            Auth::guard('seller')->LoginUsingId($dataSeller[0]['id_seller']);
            return redirect('/seller_login');

        } elseif (count($dataAdmin)>0) {
            //Login berhasil admin
            Auth::guard('admin')->LoginUsingId($dataAdmin[0]['id_admin']);
            return redirect('/admin_login');
        } else {
            //Login gagal
            return "failed";
            return redirect('/masuk');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error is telling you laravel cannot find the column "id" in table "seller" so you must verify that exist.

go to your database and check that column "id" exists.

if you want to use other name for primary_key, IE 'id_seller' you need to tell laravel to look for that name instead adding

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id_seller';
```

To your seller model. also check the Documentation for laravel conventions [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: well, im using 'id_seller' as my id, is it have to be change?

Comment: laravel by convention look for "id" as primarykey.. you can tell laravel to look for another name ('id_seller' in this case) by adding  `protected $primaryKey = 'id_seller'; ` to your seller model.
check the docs about it [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: thankyou somuch!! It's already solved, i changed my all my database to id instead of id_nametable